# NSURLCache Images Using AFNetworking API

Tags: ios, image, caching, afnetworking

I have an app which is downloading images from the server. The images are approx 56 KB and there are at least 30 of them. There are times when the user either have no connection or Edge connection (Dialup).

I am using NSURLCache in my AppDelegate.h like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
    int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
    int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"] autorelease];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

But for some reason it does not cache the images. If I load all the images with internet connection available and then disconnect or use Edge network it again fetches the images.

Comment: Might not solve your problem, but: Are you aware that AFNetworking provides a category on UIImageView to make it really easy to load remote images (incl. caching!)? http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView(AFNetworking).html

Comment: Yup! I am already using that category but on Edge network (That is what I got hehe) it is super slow.

Comment: Perhaps, you should provide some more details (code) about how you load/cache the images.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*: iOS 5 and onwards supports disk caching if you use NSURLRequest's NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad cachePolicy or return the appropriate Cache-Control headers.

This issue about caching is explained in the [AFNetworking F.A.Q.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ).

In summary, it seems that on iOS, `NSURLCache` does not provide disk cache capability, even if you create an `NSURLCache` with a `diskCapacity>0` (it seems to be ignored), and the solution is to use some other implementation of `NSURLCache` like the [`SDURLCache`](https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache) suggested in the FAQ.

Comment: Actually with iOS 5 this is not true anymore. iOS 5 with NSURLCache DOES in fact store the cache on the disk. You can check it out in your library folder there will be caches folder and inside caches you will find the cache name.

Comment: @azamsharp Yep thanks for the precision. I read about this bugfix in iOS5 too, but forgot about it ;) _(But assuming the OP has the problem with its disk caching, maybe he is still testing its app in iOS4?)_

Comment: My app is iOS 6 only and testing on the device running iOS 6.

Comment: I'va had problems with disk cache even on iOS 6+. I've been talking with an Apple engineer about the issue on one of these "iOS Tech Talks" – his short answer: **"Don't use NSURLCache - it's not designed for that."** So I continued using SDURLCache, which does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to the server to ensure that it is sending back the cache-control header for each request for the NSURLCache to be of any use.  If you don't or can't get that setup (like in my scenario) you'll need to roll your own caching layer or use something like SDURLCache or RNCachingURLProtocol.